# Handle removed variable from boost serialize

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I looked at the example on the web about adding a member variable to the serialization function by incrementing the version number and adding an "if" around the serialization of that variable.

But what do I have to do if I remove a member variable? Should I just remove it from the serialization function and boost will take care of it?

This can get worst if I remove some classes that were "serialize" in the serialize function, do I need to keep them just for that serialization code or there is another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Background / Archive format compatibility

Boost Serialization is pretty lightweight in lots of scenarios.

Specifically if you don't employ object tracking/dynamic polymorphism there's a surprising amount of leeway that renders your serialization streams compatible.

Both tracking and polymorphism become a factor when serializing through (smart) pointers (to base).

Most things in the standard library, as well as in modern C++, favour value-semantics (e.g. all standard containers) and by immediate implication, play well here.

> As a specific example, I've had lots of success serializing
>
> ```
> std::map<std::string, boost::uuids::uuid>
> ```
>
> into a binary archive, and de-serializing this archive as
>
> ```
> boost::unordered_map<std::string, boost::uuids::uuid>
> // or
> boost::flat_map<std::string, boost::uuids::uuid>
> // or
> std::vector<std::pair<std::string, boost::uuids::uuid> >
> ```

None of these types (need to) store type information, so the binary streams are compatible exchangeable.

Perhaps if you want to ***rely*** on this kind of "incidental" compatibility, you may want to write **extensive tests**.

> I have a feeling you should be able to devise a [trivial archive implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/archive_reference.html#trivial) that, instead of serializing actual data, creates a "layout map" or "compatibility signature" of the data-structures involved.
>
> This could go a long way to gaining the confidence to verify archive-compatibility between distinct types

### Case Study 1: changed layout

This closely matches the original question: "How do I de-serialize old versions once a field has been removed".

Here, the key is: *`serialize` is just a function*. You can do whatever you need. Take a simple demo class that went through two versions:

```
struct MyType {
    MyType();
    MyType(std::string const& v);

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar&, unsigned);

#if DEMO_VERSION == 0

    bool hasValue;
    std::string value;

#elif DEMO_VERSION == 1

    boost::optional<std::string> value;

#endif
};
```

Obviously, there'll be different implementations for the versions.

The trick is to de-serialize to temporary variables, and then map the old semantics on the new semantics according to your business rules:

```
#if DEMO_VERSION == 0
MyType::MyType()                     : hasValue(false)          {}
MyType::MyType(std::string const &v) : hasValue(true), value(v) {}

template <typename Ar> void MyType::serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned /*file_version*/) {
    ar & hasValue & value; // life was simple in v0
}

#elif DEMO_VERSION == 1
MyType::MyType()                     : value(boost::none)       {}
MyType::MyType(std::string const &v) : value(v)                 {}

template <typename Ar> void MyType::serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned file_version) {
    switch (file_version) {
        case 0: {
            assert(Ar::is_loading::value); // should not be writing old formats
            //
            bool        old_hasValue;      // these fields no longer exist
            std::string oldValue;

            ar & old_hasValue & oldValue;

            // translate to new object semantics/layout
            value.reset();
            if (old_hasValue) value.reset(oldValue);

            break;
        }
        default: // v1+
            ar & value;
    }
}
#endif
```

You can see this process live on Coliru where program `v0` writes an object to `v0.dat`, which program `v1` successfully reads (and serializes in the new format):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/045afea4c7e59190)</kbd>**

```
BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(MyType, DEMO_VERSION)
#include <fstream>

namespace demo {
    template <typename T> void serialize(std::ostream& os, T const& obj) {
        {
            boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(os);
            oa << obj;
        }
        os.flush();
    }

    template <typename T> void save(std::string const& fname, T const& payload) {
        std::ofstream ofs(fname, std::ios::binary);
        serialize(ofs, payload);
    }

    MyType load(std::string const& fname) {
        std::ifstream ifs(fname, std::ios::binary);

        MyType obj;

        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> obj;

        return obj;
    }
}

int main(int, char** cmd) {
    std::cout << "Running " << *cmd << " with DEMO_VERSION=" << DEMO_VERSION << "\n";
    using namespace demo;

#if DEMO_VERSION == 0

    MyType payload("Forty two");
    save     ("v0.dat", payload);  // uses v0 format
    serialize(std::cout, payload); // uses v0 format

#elif DEMO_VERSION == 1

    auto loaded = load("v0.dat");  // still reads the v0 format
    serialize(std::cout, loaded);  // uses v1 format now

#endif
}
```

Prints:

```
for v in 0 1
do
    g++ -std=c++11 -Os -Wall -DDEMO_VERSION=$v main.cpp -o v$v -lboost_system -lboost_serialization
    ./v$v
done
Running ./v0 with DEMO_VERSION=0
22 serialization::archive 11 0 0 1 9 Forty two
Running ./v1 with DEMO_VERSION=1
22 serialization::archive 11 0 1 0 0 1 0 9 Forty two
```

### Case Study 2: changed/removed types

Like you said, probably the easiest thing to do would be to keep the old type for indirect de-serialization.

Referring to the section **"Background / Archive format compatibility"** above, there's another option as long as you know what you're doing, of course.

Let's assume that the above sample ("Case Study 1") was slightly different, and used a `PoorMansOptional<std::string>` that got replaces by a `boost::optional<std::string>`. You could figure out the equivalent fields to de-serialize.

> Take note of the extra item version fields that might be interspersed. Such fields are conveniently absent between items in the container examples mentioned above.